# Why is this "call" to assert seeing two arguments instead of just the one?

Tags: c++, assert, static-assert

Given [this test program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a838ef15873ef5dd):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

const std::string& const_string = "bla";
std::string const & string_const = "blabla";

static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(const_string), decltype(string_const)>::value, "Uhoh");

int main()
{
    assert(std::is_same<decltype(const_string), decltype(string_const)>::value);
}
```

Which asserts that two types are the same at compile-time and at runtime using C's assert. All of Clang, MSVC2015, and GCC report the same error, so I'm quite sure [it's me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A):

```
main.cpp:13:49: error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
    assert(std::is_same<decltype(const_string), decltype(string_const)>::value);
                                                ^
/usr/include/assert.h:91:10: note: macro 'assert' defined here
# define assert(expr)                                                   \
         ^
```

I'm just not seeing two arguments in the `assert`. What's more, the `static_assert` works just fine... So what is going on here?

Comment: I believe the preprocessor sees two "comparisons"; `std::is_same<decltype(const_string)` and `decltype(string_const)>::value`. There is no way for the preprocessor to tell that they're not.

Comment: **static_assert** is a keyword, **assert** a preprocessor macro. Preprocessor macros split arguments by `,` in a non-smart way. Additional parentheses prevent this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C preprocessor does not recognise C++ template syntax, therefore template brackets `<` and `>` are not viewed as grouping tokens by the preprocessor, they're seen as simple characters.

This means that the preprocessor will view the comma between the template parameters as a macro parameter separator, like this:

```
assert(
    std::is_same<decltype(const_string),
    decltype(string_const)>::value);
```

To force the preprocessor to see your expression as a single statement, simply wrap your `assert` parameter in an additional set of brackets:

```
assert((std::is_same<decltype(const_string), decltype(string_const)>::value));
```

`static_assert` doesn't have this limitation because it is a [C++ keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert), rather than a preprocessor macro like `assert()`. This means it fully supports C++ syntax and sees the template parameters correctly.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the `<` and `>` tokens. They mess up the preprocessor. Remember that `assert` is a macro, not a function.

Do this (add an extra set of parentheses):

```
assert((std::is_same<decltype(const_string), decltype(string_const)>::value));
       ^                                                                   ^
```